# How to create PangoFont object from TTF font file?

Tags: fonts, freetype, pango

I've been reading the gnome APIs for `pango` but cannot find a simple way to get a `PangoFont` from `ttf` font file that I have.

What are the sequence calls for getting a `PangoFont` object from a `TTF` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(@Griffin of couple of hours ago) To add the font from a `TTF` file you need to first make sure it is first added to `FcConfig` and then retrieve its `PangoFont` via its `pango_font_description_from_string` as below:

```
//first add to FcConfig
std::string FontPath = "/path/to/font.ttf"
const FcChar8 * fontFile = (const FcChar8 *)FontPath.c_str();
FcBool fontAddStatus = FcConfigAppFontAddFile(FcConfigGetCurrent(), fontFile);

//then retrieve it via its fontDescriptor with pango
PangoFontDescription * desc = pango_font_description_from_string("SOME-FONT-FAMILY SOME-STYLE");
PangoFontMap* pfm = pango_cairo_font_map_get_default();
PangoFont* font =  pango_font_map_load_font(pfm, context, desc);
```